# Javascript - How to pass data to return of promise

Tags: javascript, sql, json, promise

I am not sure how to pass data to a promise function like below.
I need to parss it a JSON object that is then used in my MSSQL query, but if i remove the function around the promise, it says that data is undefined.

The code below is functional, I am just looking for a cleaner way to do this.

```
routes.post('/save', function(req, res){
var insert = function(data) {
        sql.connect(config)
            .then(pool => {
                return pool.request()
                    .input('first_name', sql.VarChar(100), data.firstName)
                    .input('last_name', sql.VarChar(100), data.lastName)
                    .query('INSERT INTO Uncomplete_registration (first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name)')
            }).then(result => {
            console.dir(result)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.dir(err)
        })

        sql.on('error', err => {
            console.dir("other error: " + err);
        })
    }
    insert(req.body.data);
});
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this but I am not sure how...

Comment: Do you mean "[pass](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pass#English)" instead of "[parse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parse#English)"? Both *almost* make sense here, but they mean very different things.

Comment: Is `req.body.data` defined ?

Comment: @SergeK edited my code to make it easier to understand, but yea req.body.data is defined... I am just looking for a cleaner way to pass data.

Comment: the code above works... I am just looking for a cleaner way to do it !

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking for help with?  What is the question?

Comment: _" I need to parse it a JSON object "_ -- So again, parse or pass? (After your edit it is "parss" - LOL)

Comment: Since you're looking for "how can I improve this" help, I think your question would be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does `const data = req.body.data` not do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
routes.post('/save', function(req, res){
    var data = req.body.data;
    sql.connect(config)
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .input('first_name', sql.VarChar(100), data.firstName)
                .input('last_name', sql.VarChar(100), data.lastName)
                .query('INSERT INTO Uncomplete_registration (first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name)')
        }).then(result => {
        console.dir(result)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.dir(err)
    })

    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.dir("other error: " + err);
    })
});
```

This makes `data` into a local variable, which is essentially what your function is doing. The promise .then/.catch can then access it as a closure variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
routes.post("/save", function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body.data;
    sql.connect(config)
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .input("first_name", sql.VarChar(100), data.firstName)
                .input("last_name", sql.VarChar(100), data.lastName)
                .query("INSERT INTO Uncomplete_registration (first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name)");
        }).then(result => {
        console.dir(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.dir(err);
    });
    sql.on("error", err => {
        console.dir("other error: " + err);
    });
});
```